# Test if a value is a function in jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I have a JS file which contains a class. It looks like this:

```
// testClass.js

const loaders = {
  "model": (arg1)=> {
     // do something to return models data
  },
  "events": (arg2)=> {
      // do something to return events data
   }
}


export default class TestClass{
  constructor(config){
     this.loader = loaders[config.type]   // I want to test this line
  }
}
```

I am writing a unit test for this file. In the unit test I want to check if `this.loader` is set correctly or not. Basically, I want to test if the correct function is assigned as `this.loader` or not.

Here's my unit test file

```
// testClass.test.js

import TestClass from './testClass'

describe('TestClass', ()=> {
  test('The constructor sets the loader correctly', ()=> {

      const testClassObj = new TestClass({type: 'model'})

      expect(typeof testClassObj.loader).toBe("function")   // What else can I test apart from the type?


  })
})
```

The only thing I am able to test here is the `type`. I am checking whether its a function or not.

My question is: What else can I test here? What more do I test if the expected value is a function?

Answer (score 2):

Make an assertion for the data `type` and function name. Besides, you can test the `loader` function and make an assertion for it to verify the `loader` function is really what you need and it executes correctly.

`testClass.js`:

```js
const loaders = {
  model: (arg1) => {
    // do something to return models data
    console.log('do something to return models data');
  },
  events: (arg2) => {
    // do something to return events data
  },
};

export default class TestClass {
  constructor(config) {
    this.loader = loaders[config.type];
  }
}
```

`testClass.test.js`:

```js
import TestClass from './testClass';

describe('TestClass', () => {
  test('The constructor sets the loader correctly', () => {
    jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const testClassObj = new TestClass({ type: 'model' });
    expect(typeof testClassObj.loader).toBe('function');
    expect(testClassObj.loader.name).toBe('model');
    testClassObj.loader();
    expect(console.log).toBeCalledWith('do something to return models data');
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59352068/ testClass.test.js (10.165s)
  TestClass
    ✓ The constructor sets the loader correctly (27ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    do something to return models data

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.273s
```